What is the exact formula for the electric field of a finite length cylinder with a constant surface charge density?
To formally state the problem. What is the electric field coming from an open-ended cylindrical surface that has a constant surface charge. The surface can be described in cylindrical coordinates mathematically as...
$$
S = \{ (r,\theta,z) | \forall z \in [-l/2,l/2] \; \forall \theta \in [0,2\pi] \}
$$
I have looked very hard online to try and find the exact formula for the electric field coming from a surface such as this, and have come up short. I have found papers and websites addressing variants of this question but nothing with these exact specifications that is not behind a paywall. This is odd because I could easily find exact formulas for analogous formulas for Magnetic fields, Finite Solinoid. If anyone can cite a paper that solves the problem from start to finish and gives the final answer that would be great. It seems like an involved calculation, almost surely involving elliptic integrals as the exact equation for the finite solenoid would suggest, but not so hard that it would never be addressed in an analytical format. It seems like just a coulomb integral over the surface of a finite cylinder. Similar problems have been found on this site but with finite potentials at the surface of a cylinder using Laplace's equation which is unphysical to this problem. Taking the potential to infinity at the surface for these solutions seems dubious and I'm unclear where the charge density then comes into play.
The approach I have begun is setting up the following integral using Coulomb's law.
$$
\vec{E}(\vec{r}) = \frac{\sigma\omega}{4\pi\epsilon} \int^{l/2}_{-l/2}\int^{2\pi}_{0} \frac{\vec{r} - \vec{s}}{|\vec{r} - \vec{s}|^3} d\theta dz
$$
where...
$$
\vec{s} = \omega\cos(\theta) \hat{x} 
+\omega\sin(\theta) \hat{y} 
+z \hat{z}
$$

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

So after many days of work and many mistakes and dead ends, I believe I have found a solution to the question above. I would love for anyone to check my work to make sure that this is the correct answer. The calculation is very hard so there are many opportunities for making mistakes. I will put the answer here but the full derivation is thoroughly described in this paper  I wrote that goes through the setup and solving of the problem as well as a short analysis of its correspondence with the infinite cylinder case.
Here is the solution...
$$
\vec{E}(\rho, \zeta) = E_\rho(\rho,\zeta)\hat{\rho} + E_z(\rho,\zeta)\hat{z}
$$
$$
E_z(\rho,\zeta) = -\frac{\sigma\omega}{\pi\varepsilon_0} \left[ \frac{K\left( \frac{4\rho\omega}{z'^2 + (\rho + \omega)^2} \right)}{\sqrt{z'^2 + (\rho + \omega)^2}} \right]^{z'=\zeta+l/2}_{z'=\zeta-l/2}
$$
$$
E_\rho(\rho, \zeta) = \frac{\sigma\omega}{2\pi\varepsilon_0\rho} \left[ \frac{z'}{\sqrt{z'^2+(\rho+\omega)^2}} \left( \frac{\rho-\omega}{\rho+\omega} \Pi\left(\frac{4\omega\rho}{(\rho+\omega)^2} \ , \ \frac{4\omega\rho}{z'^2+(\rho+\omega)^2}\right)+\cdots \right.\right.
$$
$$
\left. \left. \cdots + K\left(\frac{4\omega\rho}{z'^2+(\rho+\omega)^2}\right)\right)\right]^{z'=\zeta+l/2}_{z'=\zeta-l/2}
$$
Where...
$\sigma \sim$ Surface charge density of the cylinder
$\omega \sim$ Radius of the cylinder
$l \sim$ Length of the cylinder
$\rho \sim$ The radial coordinate in cylindrical coordinates
$\zeta \sim$ The z coordinate in cylindrical coordinates
$K(m) \sim$ The complete elliptic integral of the first kind
$\Pi(n,m) \sim$ The complete elliptic integral of the third kind
$$
K(m) = \int^{\pi/2}_{0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-m\sin^2(\theta)}} d\theta
$$
$$
\Pi(n,m) = \int^{\pi/2}_{0} \frac{1}{(1-n\sin^2(\theta))\sqrt{1-m\sin^2(\theta)}} d\theta
$$

Please up vote this so others in the future don't have to search as hard as I did.

+1 I used Mathematica to numerically confirm at a few points that your final result matches your initial integral. Congratulations!

You should remove the ellipses in your equation for $E_\rho$ because they are supposed to indicate that terms are missing.
